# Mongodb: sort documents by array objects

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I would like to return the documents in an order sorted by which holds the lowest `foo.bar` value (which are array objects).

I can do `db.collection.find().sort({foo.0.bar: 1})`, but this only matches the first element in the array - and as you can see in the exampe below would sort item 1 first (foo.0.bar = 5), wheras I am looking to return item 2 first `(foo.2.bar = 4)` as it has the object with the lowest value.

```
{
    "name": "Item 1",
    "foo": [
        {
            "bar": 5
        },
        {
            "bar": 6
        },
        {
            "bar": 7
        }
    ]
}
{
    "name": "item 2",
    "foo": [
        {
            "bar": 6
        },
        {
            "bar": 5
        },
        {
            "bar": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: db.collection.find().sort({foo.bar: 1})

Answer (score 19):

It seems mongo *can* do this.

For example, if I have the following documents:

```js
{ a:{ b:[ {c:1}, {c:5 } ] } }
{ a:{ b:[ {c:0}, {c:12} ] } }
{ a:{ b:[ {c:4}, {c:3 } ] } }
{ a:{ b:[ {c:1}, {c:9 } ] } }
```

And run the following:

```js
db.collection.find({}).sort({ "a.b.c":1 });
// produces:
{ a:{ b:[ {c:0}, {c:12} ] } }
{ a:{ b:[ {c:1}, {c:5 } ] } }
{ a:{ b:[ {c:1}, {c:9 } ] } }
{ a:{ b:[ {c:4}, {c:3 } ] } }

db.collection.find({}).sort({ "a.b.c":-1 });
// produces:
{ a:{ b:[ {c:0}, {c:12} ] } }
{ a:{ b:[ {c:1}, {c:9 } ] } }
{ a:{ b:[ {c:1}, {c:5 } ] } }
{ a:{ b:[ {c:4}, {c:3 } ] } }
```

As you can see, the sort by `{"a.b.c":1}` takes the **min** of all values in the array and sorts on that, whereas the sort by `{"a.b.c":-1}` takes the **max** of all the values.

Comment: Both of your outputs are producing the same result. Is that correct?

Comment: you have to look closely. first result is asceding 0, 1, 1, 3. second is descending 12,9,5,4.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to using map/reduce, is to store the min value from the array out as a separate field in the document which you could then order on. When you add to the array, you also update this field if the new value is lower than the currently recorded minimum.

e.g. your first document would become this (note "minbar added"):

```
{
    "name": "Item 1",
    "minbar" : 5,
    "foo": [
        {
            "bar": 5,
        }
        {
            "bar": 6,
        }
        {
            "bar": 7,
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea - and would work well in this specific example. But on a more complex schema where this may need to be done for multiple arrays (i.e. my real world schema) it would become a little messy.

Answer (score 4):

You can do such a sort with aggregate command from mongo version 2.2:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$foo"},
    {$project: {bars:"$foo.bar"}},
    {$group: {_id:"$_id",min:{$min: "$bars"}}},
    {$sort: {min:1}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this in mongo. You would need to use map/reduce to retrieve the min val in each array and then sort by that min value

Comment: Thanks. But what would the map/reduce function look like in the example?