# Data structure for movie ticketing system in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am trying to make a booking system for a cinema with MongoDB.

I keep all the information about the movie in a model `Movie`, including `title`, `description`, `actors`, `rating`, `director`, etc.

However, a movie can be shown in the cinema in different rooms and at different dates, so I also have a model `Showtime`, where I have `room`, `price`, and `date`.

Finally, I also need a model `Ticket` with fields `purchasedBy`, `purchasedAt`, `isRedeemed`, etc.

However, I don't know how to link the models and extract the showtimes. I want a list on the frontpage with all the movies (with title, description and image), but I also want to show the date and price. The problem is that date and price can vary since each movie can have multiple (and different) dates and prices, so I just want to show the smallest price and soonest date.

At the moment, I have a schema that looks like something like

```
movieSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  image: String,
  showtimes: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Showtime' }]
});
```

I could get a date and price by just taking the first showtime in the array of showtimes

```
Movie.find().populate('showtimes').then(movies => {
  movies.forEach(movie => {
    console.log(movie.showtimes[0].date)
    console.log(movie.showtimes[0].price)
  });
});
```

However, I need to sort by the most recent date and/or the lowest price, so I am not sure if my data structure is appropriate for this purpose.

What would be ideal, would be to be able to do something like this:

```
Movie.find().sort('showtimes.date showtimes.price').populate('showtimes').then(movies => {
  ...
});
```

but since I am only storing the IDs of the showtimes in my `showtimes` field, this is not possible.

Alternatively, I could change the schema to

```
showtimeSchema = Schema({
  date: Date,
  price: Number
});

movieSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  image: String,
  showtimes: [showtimeSchema]
});
```

so I don't have to use `populate()`. However, the problem is that when a customer buys a ticket, I need to refer to the showtime in the ticket object, so I need a model for showtimes on its own.

## Edit

As mentioned in the comments, it might be clever to embed the documents directly in `movieSchema`. However, I don't know what my `Ticket` model should look like.

Right now it is something like

```
ticketSchema = Schema({
  showtime: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Showtime' }
  purchasedAt: Date,
  purchasedBy: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
  isRedeemed: Boolean
})
```

So when I am printing the ticket, I have to do something like

```
Ticket.findById(ticketId).populate({
  path: 'Showtime',
  populate: {
    path: 'Movie'
  }
}).then(ticket => {
  console.log(ticket.date);
  console.log(ticket.event.name);
});
```

Comment: If you actually really need to query that way then embedding is the way to go. All `.populate()` does is issue another query to MongoDB in order to get the other information from another collection. It really is basically superseded by `$lookup` in modern MongoDB releases, since it was really just created to "emulate" a join, where `$lookup` "actually does" the join. But nonetheless, a "join" is the wrong thing to do performance wise and therefore you should actually keep the "related" data in the same document.

Comment: The reason it was a "comment" is because your question was bordering on asking for opinions or generally being too broad. So actually editing it in a way that now directly asks for opinions, or basically "broadening the subject" is not doing you any favors. Perhaps you actually have [A New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) or indeed several in order to work out the concepts you need to understand related to one use case or the other. You would probably get more information than from "one big question" that way as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use your second schema; there's really no sense in creating a new model/collection for the showtimes since you won't be making transactions on the showtime, but on visitors, movies, and tickets. So that looks like this:

```
movieSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  image: String,
  showtimes: [{
    date: Date,
    price: Number
  }]
});
```

Then, what you can do is [sort by the min/max values of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315658/mongodb-sort-documents-by-array-objects). So that would look something like this:

```
Movie.find().sort({'name.showtimes.date' : -1, price: 1})
```

This takes the latest showtimes for each movie and sorts by that time (as well as lowest price).

### EDIT:

You could have a reference to the movie in the ticket, and store the showtime there as well:

```
ticketSchema = Schema({
  showtime: Date,
  purchasedAt: Date,
  purchasedBy: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
  isRedeemed: Boolean,
  movie: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Movie' }
})
```

If you need more structure than that for whatever reason, I would look at using SQL instead. Nested populates (essentially SQL JOINs) are a maintenance/optimization nightmare, and RDBMS are more suited for data like that.

### EDIT 2:

Ok, let's weigh our options here. You are right, in the event of a time/venue change, you would have to update all tickets. So storing the showtime separately gives us that benefit. On the other hand, this now adds a layer of complexity to virtually *every single* ticket you look up, not to mention the performance detriment and added server costs. Even if ticket/venue changes happen frequently, I'm almost positive that your ticket lookups are much more frequent.

That being said, I think a good approach here is to store an `_id` on the showtime subojects, and lookup your tickets that way:

```
showtimeSchema = Schema({
  date: Date,
  price: Number
});

movieSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  image: String,
  // When you use a sub-schema like this, mongoose creates
  // an `_id` for your objects.
  showtimes: [showtimeSchema]
});

// Now you can search movies by showtime `_id`.
Movie.find({showtimes: 'some showtime id'}).exec()
```

You could go one step farther here and register a [static](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html) on the `Movie` model for easy lookup by showtime `_id`:

```
Movie.findByShowtime('some showtime id').exec()
```

When you've fetched the movie, you can grab the showtime like this:

```
var st = movie.showtimes.id('some showtime id');
```

[Further reading on subdocuments.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how I could structure my tickets. I have updated my question

Comment: Edited. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: But if I, for instance, have to change the venue or date in the showtime, it won't affect all the tickets. Could I refer to the showtime object stored in the showtimes array of movie directly in the ticket?

Comment: I think I understand your issue. Edited.